# axios get and promise function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, es6-promise

i'm training to do an axios call with promise, but wihtout success

```
import axios from "axios";

export class ContiService {
  getConti() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        const URL =
          process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_PATH + process.env.REACT_APP_RESOURCE_CONTI;
        console.log(URL);

        return axios(URL, {
          method: "GET",
          headers: { "content-type": "application/json", preferences: "" },
        });

        resolve(/* ??? */);
      }, 300);
    });
  }
}
```

---

```
export default class Posizionecliente extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.contiService = new ContiService();
    this.state = {
      conti: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.contiService.getConti().then(r => this.setState({ conti: r.data.conti }));
  }
}
```

How can complete this with promise?

The call does not work at the moment, where should I place resolve?

Comment: Why a timeout of 300? Anyway, `axios` return a Promise, so no need to wrap it in your own. Simply return the `axios()` call from `getConti`. Or are you deliberately including a custom Promise? In that case you need to `resolve(axios(...));`

Comment: I can't, because i have a rendering problem, and if i save a json in this state, and try to write it in render, it's undefined!

Comment: Why are you setting a content-type on a GET request? A GET request has no content to describe the type of.

Comment: You need to write your `render` in a way that it'll work regardless of the state. Also, how is a timeout going to fix the render issue? The component will be rendered before the axios call has finished regardless. Anyway, here's a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/zwnn067xr4

Comment: I don't know, an user suggest me this code

Answer (score 2):

The key here is to realize that `axios` itself returns a promise. So there are a couple of ways to approach this.

In either case, there is no need for `setTimeout`.

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    const URL = process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_PATH+process.env.REACT_APP_RESOURCE_CONTI;
    axios(URL, {
                   method: 'GET',
                   headers: {'content-type': 'application/json', 'preferences' : ''}
               }
    )
    .then(response=> resolve(response.data))
    .catch(err => reject(err))
}
```

Or alternately, and perhaps more clearly, simply return the `axios` call itself, which will return the promise and allow your component logic to handle state accordingly

```
getConti() {
    const URL = process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_PATH+process.env.REACT_APP_RESOURCE_CONTI;
    return axios(URL, {
                   method: 'GET',
                   headers: {'content-type': 'application/json', 'preferences' : ''}
               }
    )
}
```

You don't have to change your component logic (except perhaps to handle promise rejections).

```
this.contiService.getConti().then(r => this.setState({ conti: r.data.conti }));
```

The `.then` will handle the successful completion of the axios call.

Here's a good read on [`Promise Chaining`](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining). See in particular, the section on [returning promises.](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining#returning-promises)

Comment: *there is no need for setTimeout* - moreover, there's no need for `new Promise` then. The first snippet in the answer is called promise construction antipattern.

Comment: @estus Correct. That is why I provided the second and clearer example. There could be reasons for the first example, however, if response data needs to be transformed or other methods need to be called, etc, before returning the data, but for the example given, you are right, there is no need for `new Promise`

Comment: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'conti' of undefined

Comment: @mantegnous At this point, you need to debug the response you are getting back from your API call. Use `console.log` wherever you can.

Comment: *There could be reasons for the first example* - actually, no, all transformations may go to `then`. `new Promise` just introduces additional level of nesting without benefits, that's why snippet 1 is an antipattern and snippet 2 is not just alternative but preferred way to do this.

Comment: .then(response=> resolve(response.data))
    .catch(err => reject(err)) i can't write this, because the response is in another file

Comment: @estus fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

If a promise is resolved with another promise, it will adopt the new one. Therefore:

```
const request = axios(URL, etc);
resolve(request);
```

Don't `return`. `setTimeout` doesn't do anything with the return value of the function it executes.

Comment: "axios i not a function"

Comment: Then something went wrong with your import, and your existing code would have errored on it too.